# Two very alike select statements different performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I've just came across some weird performance differences.

I have two selects:

```
SELECT s.dwh_end_date,
       t.*,
       '-1' as PROMOTION_DROP_EMP_CODE,
       trunc(sysdate +1) as PROMOTION_END_DATE,
      'K01' as PROMOTION_DROP_REASON,
       -1 as PROMOTION_DROP_WO_NUMBER
FROM STG_PROMO_EXPIRE_DATE t
INNER JOIN fct_customer_services s
 ON(t.dwh_product_key = s.dwh_product_key)
```

Which takes approximately 20 seconds.

And this one:

```
SELECT s.dwh_end_date,
       s.dwh_product_key,
       s.promotion_expire_date,
       s.PROMOTION_DROP_EMP_CODE,
       s.PROMOTION_END_DATE,
       s.PROMOTION_DROP_REASON,
       s.PROMOTION_DROP_WO_NUMBER
FROM STG_PROMO_EXPIRE_DATE t
INNER JOIN fct_customer_services s
 ON(t.dwh_product_key = s.dwh_product_key)
```

That takes approximately 400 seconds

They are basically the same - its just to assure that I've updated my data correct (first select is to update the FCT tables) second select to make sure every thing updated correctly.

The only differences between this two selects, is the columns I select. (STG table has two columns - dwh_p_key and prom_expire_date)

[First select explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrrJr.png)

[Second select explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lcI1.png)

What can cause this weird behaviour?..

The FCT tables is indexed UNIQUE (dwh_product_key, dwh_end_date) and partitioned by dwh_end_date (250 million records), the STG doesn't have any indexes (and its only 15k records)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste the explain plans and not have an image

Comment: Are those times to return all rows or just the first page of results? And are they consistent if you run both queries repeatedly, or are you perhaps just seeing the effect of block caching? And the plans are *not* the same, look at the bottom two lines again for a start, and the bytes values. Index full scan vs. full table scan is a significant difference.

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right, didn't catch it with my eye.. and yes, they are repeatedly, no matter how many times i run them those are the results.. why this dramatic differences occurring ?

Comment: The plain text display of an execution plan is much better then an image. The text version of the plan contains much more information that is helpful then the image does. So in the future, please add execution plans as (formatted) _text_, not as images (and definitely not as an image of your complete SQL client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plans are *not* exactly the same. The first query uses a fast full scan of the index on `fct_customer_services` and doesn't need to access any blocks from the actual table, since you only refer to the two indexed columns.

The second query does have to access the table blocks to get the other unidexed column values. It's doing a full table scan - slower and more expensive than a full index scan. The optimiser doesn't see any improvement from using the index and then accessing specific table rows, presumably because the cardinality is too high - it needs to access too many table rows to save any effort by hitting the index first. Doing so would be even slower.

So the second query is slower because it has to read the whole table from disk/cache rather than just the whole index, and the table is much larger than the index. You can look at the segments assigned to both objects (index and table) to see the ratio of their sizes.

Comment: But if the query already accessed the tabled and got the dwh_product_key , why when picking another column from the same row requires different access to the table?

Comment: @Yossi - in the first query it only has to look at the index to get both dwh_product_key (for the join) and dwh_end_date (for the select list). Nothing else is required from the other table columns. In the second query promotion_expire_date is *not* in that index, it is only in the actual table. It doesn't access the table twice, it does a single full table scan to get dwh_product_key **and** all the other column values it needs for the select lost.

Comment: Great , Thanks . @AlexPoole